# Vertical partitioning in Entity Framework Code First

Tags: entity-framework

I use Entity Framework Code First to access my SQL Server database. The "Client" table currently has about 90 columns:

```
[Table("Clients")]
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property90 { get; set; }
}
```

I have decided to vertically partition this table into 3 tables, because often not all the properties are used. However, I still have legacy code (that I can't change right now) that expects the full Client object with all 90 columns.

My solution so far is to split the Client class into 3 classes corresponding with the new tables, and then use Table Per Type inheritance to allow the legacy code to access the Client object as though the original Clients table is still there:

```
[Table("Clients")]
public class Client: Client1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property30 { get; set; }
}
[Table("Client1s")]
public class Client1: Client2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property31 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property60 { get; set; }
}
[Table("Client2s")]
public class Client2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property61 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property90 { get; set; }
}
```

However, this somehow seems a bit clunky to me.

**Is there a more elegant way to achieve vertical partitioning with Entity Framework Code First?**

Answer (score 0):

So, considering you refer to the existing approach as being used by "legacy" systems and your new partitioned approach is most likely intended to be the new "correct" way going forwards, my advice would be to keep them as separated as possible.

What you could look to do is replace the existing monolithic Clients table with a database view that joins the 3 separate, partitioned tables back together. Then you can hook up the existing Clients class in all it's former glory to the view, leaving your legacy systems relatively untouched, in theory.

I'd also recommend ditching the inheritance idea and leaving the 3 new partitioned classes completely independent of one another. Otherwise, both legacy and new systems will be extremely sensitive to any changes being made to classes and properties within that entire inheritance chain.

By doing it this way you are then free to change and evolve the new classes independently and modify any underlying table structures however you see fit in the future. Providing you maintain the views integrity and consistency, your legacy systems should continue to function as normal without any repercussions or regressions, mostly :-)

In my humble experience, shielding the old from changes in the new far outway the slight inconveniences of having some code duplication and stricter boundaries.

To answer your elegance question more directly I'd say that insulating your classes against unnecessary coupling and avoiding the "ripple effect" yields the more elegant solution.

Anyway, I hope it helps.

*I'm going to assume your actual classes have much more meaningful property names, right?*

```
// LEGECY SYSTEMS
[Obsolete("Use the newer partitioned classes going forwards")]
[Table("vClients")]
public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property90 { get; set; }
}

// NEW STRUCTURES
[Table("Client1s")]
public class Client1
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property1 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property30 { get; set; }
}
[Table("Client2s")]
public class Client2
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property31 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property60 { get; set; }
}
[Table("Client3s")]
public class Client3
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Property61 { get; set; }
    ...
    public string Property90 { get; set; }
}
```

Updating the the base tables via the view can be done using some INSTEAD OF triggers, like so:

```
CREATE TRIGGER ClientsLegacyInsertAdapter on vClients
INSTEAD OF INSERT
AS
BEGIN
BEGIN TRANSACTION
INSERT INTO Client1s
   SELECT Id, PropertyA1, Property2, ..., Property30
   FROM inserted;

INSERT INTO Client2s
   SELECT Id, Property31, Property32, ..., Property60
   FROM inserted;

INSERT INTO Client3s
   SELECT Id, Property61, Property62, ..., Property90
   FROM inserted;
COMMIT TRANSACTION
END
```

You should be able to use the same technique for UPDATE and DELETE commands also.

Comment: Yes, the property names I used her are simplified. They are not my real names :-)

Comment: Your suggestion is to have 3 separate tables plus a view that JOINs the 3 tables to cater to the legacy code. I can see how this would work for read operations. However, the legacy code also writes to the Clients table - most often it writes a complete record. Not sure these INSERTS and UPDATES will work against this proposed view.

Comment: Yes sorry for not being more precise. One way to achieve what you want is to apply some INSTEAD OF triggers on the view that take the full parameter set and apply inserts and updates to the 3 base tables. I'll update my answer with a crude example

Comment: @user1147862 This combination of techniques have worked out pretty well for me in the past when migrating older systems to newer ones. Without knowing more about the application context and specific use cases your systems must adhere to I cannot say that it will work exactly as I have described it. But hopefully it will point you in the right direction.